# Google translate english monolingual definitions

Tags: licensing, english

Is google translate monolingual definitions open for commercial use? Am I violating intellectual property  to use english words definitions in my english quiz app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the [Google Translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs) then you are allowed commercial use. But there is no free quota for the API ([terms of service](https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/terms), [pricing](https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/faq#pricing)). If you are a paying customer, you can use the translations for commercial use (with attribution if you use them directly).

I suspect you are not talking about the paid API but instead either scraping yourself or using a package like [goslate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/goslate). These tools are against the Terms of Google so you may find that they aren't very stable (goslate works by faking a user-agent). Building a commercial app based on these data sources is probably not a good idea. See the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22587237/2327328) for more discussion.

(if you want simple, single word translations with a flexible license, check out using Anki decks, [for example](https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/4018499214))

Answer (score 2):

The official Google Translate API does *not* offer dictionary data.  (If you must know: Google has traditionally paid for licences for dictionary data from various sources, with varying quality, for the various languages.)  So I assume you are scraping and thus on poor legal footing, but I doubt it will be a problem in practice.

One great and ever-improving source of dictionary data is [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org).  There are well-tested open-source parsers and clients available, just like for Wikipedia.